# Problem with inheritance and List<>

Tags: .net, linq, inheritance, list

I have an abstract class called Grouping. I have a subclass called GroupingNNA.

```
public class GroupingNNA : Grouping {
  // blah blah blah
}
```

I have a List that contains items of type GroupingNNA, but is actually declared to contain items of type Grouping.

```
List<Grouping> lstGroupings = new List<Grouping>();
lstGroupings.Add(
  new GroupingNNA { fName = "Joe" });
lstGroupings.Add(
  new GroupingNNA { fName = "Jane" });
```

**The Problem:**
The following LINQ query blows up on me because of the fact that lstGroupings is declared as List< Grouping> and fName is a property of GroupingNNA, not Grouping.

```
var results = from g in lstGroupings
              where r.fName == "Jane"
              select r;
```

Oh, and this is a compiler error, not a runtime error. Thanks in advance for any help on this one!

**More Info:**
Here is the actual method that won't compile. The OfType() fixed the LINQ query, but the compiler doesn't like the fact that I'm trying to return the anonymous type as a List< Grouping>.

```
private List<Grouping> ApplyFilterSens(List<Grouping> lstGroupings, string fSens) {

  // This works now! Thanks @Lasse
  var filtered = from r in lstGroupings.OfType<GroupingNNA>()
                 where r.QASensitivity == fSens
                 select r;

  if (filtered != null) {
    **// Compiler doesn't like this now**
    return filtered.ToList<Grouping>();
  }
  else
    return new List<Grouping>();
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
= from g in lstGroupings.OfType<GroupingNNA>()
```

this will skip any elements not of type `GroupingNNA`, and also make the compiler use `GroupingNNA` as the type for `g`.

In response to comment and edited question. No, the compiler will certainly not be happy about your changed collection, but you can fix that:

```
return new List<Grouping>(filtered.ToArray());
```

This relies on the fact that arrays in .NET are co/contra-variant, which allows the compiler to treat `GroupingNNA[]` as `Grouping[]` for the constructor.

Also, you don't need the `if (filtered != null)` check, you will get a collection in `filtered`, it might just not produce any elements, but `filtered` will always be non-`null`.

This means your code can be written as:

```
var filtered = from r in lstGroupings.OfType<GroupingNNA>()
               where r.QASensitivity == fSens
               select r;
return new List<Grouping>(filtered.ToArray());
```

or even just:

```
return new List<Grouping>((from r in lstGroupings.OfType<GroupingNNA>()
                           where r.QASensitivity == fSens
                           select r).ToArray());
```

or even shorter if you drop the linq syntax:

```
return new List<Grouping>((lstGroupings.OfType<GroupingNNA>()
    .Where(r => r.QASensitivity == fSens).ToArray());
```

Note that you can of course use `OfType` to go the other way as well:

```
return filtered.OfType<Grouping>().ToList();
```

there shouldn't be any big performance differences between the different ways here, if in doubt, measure it, but I would go with what you find easiest to read and understand.

Comment: Thank you! I'm one step closer now. However, the compiler isn't happy now because I'm trying to return the anonymous type as a List< Grouping>. I'll make an edit to my original post with some more code so you can see what I'm talking about. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `ToList<AnotherType>()` is putting yourself back in the same boat as before - generic covariance/contravarience is not supported - e.g. `List<Type>` is not compatible with or convertible to/from `List<SubType>`.

You need to use `filtered.OfType<Grouping>().ToList();` - the first gets you back to an `IEnumerable<Grouping>` instead of an `IEnumerable<GroupingNNA>`, and then `ToList` just converts the `IEnumerable` to a `List` of the same generic type.

Comment: .NET 2.x through 3.5 Generic Lists are invarient. This is for your own good. Look to .NET 4.0 for support of more loose typing in generics